# Generating a link to AWS Mangement Console from ARN

Tags: amazon-web-services

If I have an [Amazon Resource Name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html) (ARN) like "arn:aws:config:ap-southeast-2:1234567890:config-rule/config-rule-h0e6s3" how would I get a link to the appropriate management interface?

Is there a lookup through the AWS SDK or a magic URL to generate a link or use a global redirect point (e.g. https://aws.amazon.com/resource/arn:aws:config:ap-southeast-2:1234567890:config-rule/configu-rule-h0e6s3) to the appropriate place on the management console where you would manage that item?

Comment: I don't think there's an official solution, but in cases I found when researching something similar, recently, if you can navigate to a place that displays a list including that resource in the console, and then search for that resource in the search box, you should find that the URL reflects the identifier of that specific resource, which you can then use to craft other URLs.

Comment: any luck ? i'm stuck on the same issue

Answer (score 5):

There is now an (unofficial) tool to translate ARN to deep links into the AWS console:

https://link2aws.github.io/

You can install it locally too:

https://github.com/link2aws/link2aws.github.io

I have tested it with IAM policies, Lambda functions and few others and seems to work well. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

This would be a convenient boto addition... Alas, no.

I had to do this for an SNS topic's send & receive page.

The URLs have a section that needs to be urlencoded:

eg:

```
https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/sqs/v2/home?region=eu-central-1#/queues/https%3A%2F%2Fsqs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com%2F123123123123%2Fsns-name/send-receive#/
```

Note everything between the 2nd 'https' and the final / is encoded.
If you encode the final / it doesn't work.

Here's the snippet that built the URL:

```
console_base = f"https://{region}.console.aws.amazon.com/sqs/v2/home?region={region}#/queues"
sns_relative = f"https://sqs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/{account_id}/{sns_topic_name}"
sns_url = f'{console_base}/{urllib.parse.quote_plus(sns_relative)}/send-receive'
```

Answer (score -4):

I think this is the support page you want to read: [Your AWS Account ID and Its Alias](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/console_account-alias.html).

> Your sign-in page URL has the following format, by default.
>   https://Your_AWS_Account_ID.signin.aws.amazon.com/console/

You account ID is the long number in the ARN, right after the region.

Comment: I'm looking to deep link to the management interface for specific resources. For example, given an EC2 instance, deep link me to the part of the management console where that is.

Comment: You can only link this far: https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=eu-west-1#Instances:sort=instanceState
Otherwise you would already have know the EC2 instance id to produce a link like this: https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=eu-west-1#Instances:instanceId=i-12340b880d43a06e9;sort=instanceId

Comment: account ID and resource ARN are different.